# jOOQ code generation: forcedType

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm currently evaluating jOOQ. And we have problems with creating join statements, like this:

```
create.select( )
        .from( TABLEA, TABLEB)
        .where(TABLEA.ID.equal( TABLEB.TABLEA_ID ));
```

Because of a type mismatch. In the (Oracle 11g) Database TABLEA is `NUMBER(22,0)`, but TABLEB.TABLEA_ID is `NUMBER(7,0)`.

Therefore jOOQ generates for the first property a `BigInteger` field, but for the latter a `Integer` field.

So I tried to generate all `NUMBER(.*,0)` with `BigInteger` with the following xml:

```
    <forcedTypes>
        <forcedType>
          <name>DECIMAL_INTEGER</name>
          <expression>.*</expression>
          <types>NUMBER(.*,0)</types>
        </forcedType>
    </forcedTypes>

</database>
```

But this did not work. I still have fields with `Integer` as type. So what can I do about that, beside changing the table column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [#2485](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2486) is not yet implemented in jOOQ 3.4, so you cannot match length, precision, scale yet. I realise that the manual seems to indicate otherwise, which is wrong...

If this is only happening occasionally, you can also resort to manipulating data types through the jOOQ API. Here are some options:

```
// This will render an actual cast in the generated SQL statement
TABLEA.ID.equal( TABLEB.TABLEA_ID.cast(TABLEA.ID.getDataType()) )
TABLEA.ID.equal( TABLEB.TABLEA_ID.cast(BigInteger.class) )

// This generate a new column TABLEA_ID of type NUMBER(22, 0)
TABLEA.ID.equal( TABLEB.TABLEA_ID.coerce(TABLEA.ID.getDataType()) )
TABLEA.ID.equal( TABLEB.TABLEA_ID.coerce(BigInteger.class) )

// This is your last resort: raw types
TABLEA.ID.equal( (Field) TABLEB.TABLEA_ID )
```

Comment: unfortunately your regex didn't work either. It worked for `NUMBER`, but then it would also use `BigInteger` for `NUMBER` types with scale.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes: My bad, I'm sorry about the confusion. [#2485](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2486) is not yet implemented in jOOQ 3.4, which is why it doesn't work. The manual is wrong... I guess you'll have to resort to one of the above explicit conversions, or to write a regex matching all relevant columns in your database - e.g. all columns ending on `_ID`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try one of the workarounds.